Site Collection not visible when moved from Production to DR
My WSS_Content database contain 13 site collections. I restored this database from Prod to DR and except one, all site collections are working. In view all site collections in CA, the site is appearing but it is not showing any detail like content database, site collection administrator etc (as shown in screenshot below)

Other sites are showing all detail like they normally do (screenshot below)

Here's how this site was created/restored.

This problem site was migrated from 2013 to 2016 Prod using Mount-SPContentDatabase -AssignNewDatabaseId
After migration, I took backup using Backup-SPSite on 2016 Prod
Then I created a new site collection with same name on DR in WSS_Content database
After that I restored this site on 2016 DR using Restore-SPSite -Force. (backup taken in step 2 above)
Site started appearing on DR after that i.e. there was not issue
Then I took latest WSS_Content SQL Server backup and restored it from 2016 Prod to 2016 DR.
This is when this site disappeared as shown in screenshot above.
Opening this site in browser on DR shows 400 bad request

Running Get-SPContentDatabase on both Prod and DR shows that it has 13 sites. Running Get-SPContentDatabase -Site https://problem_site_here also shows that it is part of WSS_Content database yet site is not available on DR.
When I run Get-SPSite on Prod then it lists all site collections and their combability level is 15. Doing the same on DR also lists all site collections and their compatibility level is 15 except that problem site whose compatibility level column is empty.
Any idea why this is happening?
EDIT
Now cannot even delete site collection using Remove-SPSite neither I am able to restore is using Restore-SPSite -Force. In both cases I am getting error <nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>

SharePoint is a giant pain in the ass. I solved the issue as follows:

Applied latest CU on both Prod and DR
Then ran Products Configuration Wizrad
Then ran Uprade-SPContentDatabase
Then took latest site backup on Prod
Then force deleted site on DR using $site.ContentDatabase.ForceDeleteSite
Then restore site on DR

